# VirtualBox machine window is suddenly very small

Tags: virtualbox, display-resolution

I am running Ubuntu 16.04, and have an Ubuntu 16.04 VM running in VirtualBox. Today when I started up VirtualBox and started the VM, it didnt resize to fit my display. Instead it is stuck at 800x600, and there seems to be no way of increasing it. Auto-resize does nothing, resizing til 1920x1200 does nothing...

I even tried reinstalling VirtualBox, as I had to to do it once earlier because of some weird error. It worked fine after the first reinstall, but now suddenly the VM screen refuses to go above 800x600.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install Virtual box guest additions in the guest. This is necessary requirement. After that, your VM window will automatically fit the display to your house resolution after booting.

See this answer for complete guidance 
https://askubuntu.com/a/22745